# Finding arcs between strongly connected components

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Having a graph and all of it's strongly connected components, I was wondering what the most efficient way to find arcs that connect two SCC. All the solutions I found involve running through all the nodes, and I was wondering if there was a way to do it without having done that, in particular, during the Tarjan algorithm I used to find SCC's in the graph. ANyway to do it in a linear fashion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Scanning through all the nodes *does* take only linear time.  Perhaps I'm not understanding what you are asking.

Comment: yes but I was wondering if there was a way of doing it during Tarjan's algorithm when we are finding the SCC's

Comment: What would prevent you from doing that during Tarjan's algorithm?  I don't understand the nature of your confusion.